# Laurent series for $\exp(-1/z)\sin(1/z)$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, cauchy-integral-formula

I am trying to evaluate the integral $$\int \exp\left(-\frac{1}{z}\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)dz$$ in the deleted neighborhood $|z|=1$. This integral can be easily solved using the Cauchy integral formula, but this requires figuring out the the Laurent series since $z=0$ is an essential singularity.  Could someone please show me how to write the Laurent series in order to find the $a_{-1}$ term. Thank you

Comment: writing $\sin (1/z) = (e^{i/z} - e^{-i/z})/(2i)$ and using expression of the exponential function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\exp(-w) \sin(w)$ is an entire function.  It has Maclaurin series
$$
\exp(-w)\,\sin(w) = w - w^2 + \frac{1}{3}\,w^3 + \dots
$$
valid in the whole complex plane.  Therefore your function has a convergent Laurent series
$$
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{z}\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{z^2} +\frac{1}{3z^3} +\dots
$$
valid for all $z \ne 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the response, now I understand. $a_{-1}$=1 .